# special characters to standard binary format

Tags: c#

I prepared a method to convert input string to Binary format '0' and '1' as:

```
public static string StringToBinary(string data)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chararr = data.ToCharArray();
    foreach (char c in data.ToCharArray())
    {
        string appendedStr = Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
        sb.Append(appendedStr);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

that deal with each character as a component of 8 bits

and then i write a method that Restore the string from the binary as

```
public static string BinaryToString(string data)
{
    List<Byte> byteList = new List<Byte>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 8)
    {
        byteList.Add(Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(i, 8), 2));
    }

    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteList.ToArray());
}
```

that also deal with every 8 bits as one character , and it works fine.
But where I use characters like (ψ , ≤ , and i think all special char) it not working and return Exception from `BinaryToString` method because it converted from `StringToBinary` to 14 bit (for ≤ ), and I try to complete it to 16 bit by adding 0 to left, it returns another string sequence 
anybody have solution ??

Comment: You need to learn about Unicode encodings.

Comment: [**XY problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: .NET strings are Unicode (16 bits), not 8-bit bytes. ASCII is definitely NOT guaranteed to be the non-Unicode format used by the system, as it's controlled by the system's locale settings. Non-US computers used by non-programmers are certain to have each country's codepage used instead of ASCII

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is a bit more complicated even. A single unicode character can be spread over many more than just 2 bytes. Example: `"čč".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD)` is printed as `čč`, but `ToCharArray` gives you `cˇcˇ`. Both are the same string, but have different "in-memory" data. This also makes it somewhat tricky to compare unicode strings, because they do not necessarily need to be "byte-equal" to be "char-equal".

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that you can safely go through a char array and get a single byte out of each of the chars. That is a false assumption.

Instead, you need to encode the string to a byte array first, in a given encoding. For example:

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);
```

You can then convert each of these bytes into binary safely.

At the other hand, for every 8 bits you read, you put them back together as a single byte, and when you have the whole byte array again, you just call

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteData);
```

And you're done.

However... Why are you saving characters as binary strings? What *problem* are you actually trying to solve? If you're trying anything like compression or something, you're using extremely inefficient methods... If you need to use this to serialize data, why not use hexadecimal or Base-64 encoding?

Comment: it's OK but i want a method to iterate the output bits to change from '1' To '0' and vice , after every change i used the new bits on hashing function,  i wish you understand my issue, thanks

Comment: @MaRiO That's quite a round-about way of doing that. You have bitwise operators to do bit manipulations. For example, changing all output bits from 1 to 0 and vice versa can easily be done with `unchecked((byte)~data[i])` (where data[i] is one of the bytes). Bit operations are hardcoded in the CPU, I can think of no possibility where converting to a bit string would be better than simply using the bitwise operators (`|`, `^`, `&`, `~`, `<<`, `>>`).

Comment: Yes, the solution for special characters is the Encoding.Unicode. Unicode takes care of special characters. If you use Encoding.UTF8 then you will not be able to manage special characters. For example, "și" will be represented in binary as "19 02 69 00". The character "ș" will be correctly read with Encoding.Unicode.GetString( Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("și") ) .